# Using Joda API in Android application

Tags: android, button, jodatime

I want to get the current date and time by means of DateTime Class ,I have download Joda from http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/

and I added three jar files which are in the extracted folder to java build path of my project properties.and my code is like the following code:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;



public class TappedNFC extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tapped_nfc);
            
            
            Button BeamButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BeamButton);
            BeamButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    
                     DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                      int month = dt.getMonthOfYear();
                    
                TextView tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tx.setText(Integer.toString(month));
                
                }
            });
        }
```

but the logcat gets exception:

```
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.DateTime
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.example.tappednfc.TappedNFC$1.onClick(TappedNFC.java:28)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3460)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13955)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-04 14:57:18.309: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I haven't used Joda before,So please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you add the jars to you libs folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you added them to your build path did you use the normal (but incorrect for Android) route of "Properties" > "Java Build Path" > "Add External Jars" ? The correct way to bundle external jars in your Android project is to create a "libs" (note the plural) directory and directly paste them under the directory.

A project build will then show your dependent jars under "Android Dependencies" and they will be bundled correctly into the APK. If you don't follow that route then the external jars are not added and you'll see the sorts of exceptions you noted.

Comment: Warpzit - yep this looks like a direct duplicate. @Shadi S - resolve as a duplicate.